# Typeface. Не меняется шрифт, программа крашится.

Tags: android, java

Приветствую! Хочу поменять шрифт на текстВью-шке, при использовании такой вот конструкции происходит force close. В мануалах всюду именно этот код, шрифты разные пробовал, не помогло.

```
TextView button1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/aksent.ttf");       
        button1.setTypeface(tf);
```

Не, у меня TextView, просто id у него button.
Вот xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/pero"
            android:drawablePadding="20dp"            
            android:tag="photos_btn"
            android:text="Текст некий"
            android:textColor="#f55fff"
            android:textSize="15dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

а вот лог (вроде правильно вытащил)

```
    12-10 11:24:37.585: E/AndroidRuntime(6123): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-10 11:24:37.585: E/AndroidRuntime(6123): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.canvv/com.example.canvv.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: native typeface cannot be made
12-10 11:24:37.585: E/AndroidRuntime(6123):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1702)
12-10 11:24:37.585: E/AndroidRuntime(6123):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1722)
12-10 11:24:37.585: E/AndroidRuntime(6123):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:124)
12-10 11:24:37.585: E/AndroidRuntime(6123):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:974)
12-10 11:24:37.585: E/AndroidRuntime(6123):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-10 11:24:37.585: E/AndroidRuntime(6123):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
12-10 11:24:37.585: E/AndroidRuntime(6123):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3821)
12-10 11:24:37.585: E/AndroidRuntime(6123):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-10 11:24:37.585: E/AndroidRuntime(6123):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
12-10 11:24:37.585: E/AndroidRuntime(6123):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
12-10 11:24:37.585: E/AndroidRuntime(6123):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
12-10 11:24:37.585: E/AndroidRuntime(6123):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-10 11:24:37.585: E/AndroidRuntime(6123): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: native typeface cannot be made
12-10 11:24:37.585: E/AndroidRuntime(6123):     at android.graphics.Typeface.<init>(Typeface.java:160)
12-10 11:24:37.585: E/AndroidRuntime(6123):     at android.graphics.Typeface.createFromAsset(Typeface.java:134)
12-10 11:24:37.585: E/AndroidRuntime(6123):     at com.example.canvv.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:34)
12-10 11:24:37.585: E/AndroidRuntime(6123):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
12-10 11:24:37.585: E/AndroidRuntime(6123):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1666)
12-10 11:24:37.585: E/AndroidRuntime(6123):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: логи покажи, почему текстВью назыается баттон?

Comment: Спасибо всем за помощь! Дело оказалось в шрифте, поставил ареал и все заработало!

Answer (score 2):

По вашему коду кажется, что не инициализирована button1. Точнее инициализирована почему-то перед установкой setContentView

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
TextView button1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.button1);
Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/aksent.ttf");       
button1.setTypeface(tf);
```

ps да реально странно TextView с id button1

Comment: button1 потому что пользую TextView как кнопку, TextView у меня кастомный. Вот весь код

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  TextView button1 =     (TextView)findViewById(R.id.button1);
  Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/aksent.ttf");       
        button1.setTypeface(tf);  
 }

инициализировал баттон после setContentView, все равно вылеты

Comment: хмл покажи, это кнопка или тексвью все таки? и лог

Comment: и почему у тебя метод протектед, а н паблик? откуда столько косяков?

Comment: ну он все-таки протектед. может косяк в разметке, или манифесте. В общем действительно нужен лог

Comment: с каких пор он протектед?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onCreate%28android.os.Bundle%29

Answer (score 2):

Привет. Если у тебя Button, то делается так:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button mButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mButton);
    Typeface tp = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/aksent.ttf");
    mButton.setTypeface(tp);
}
```

А если у тебя TextView, то так:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    TextView mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mTextView);
    Typeface tp = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/aksent.ttf");
    mTextView.setTypeface(tp);
}
```

Все проверено и вполне работоспособно. Если и после этого у вас ошибка это значит, что у вас ошибка в другом месте (в других строчках кода или в разметке). И метод onCreate никак не должно быть protected, у него стандартная видимость public.

Comment: Серьезно? Свойство? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onCreate%28android.os.Bundle%29

Comment: Зачем так приператься?! Ты же понял, что метод. А человек описался, на то мы и люди, что можем совершить ошибки.

Comment: ну я про public, просто если в абстрактном классе объявлен как protected, то он может быть public или protected в наследниках

Comment: Понял тебя)))

Comment: крашится... да вроде xml-ка не мудреная. Логи отправил в шапку

Answer (score 1):

RuntimeException: native typeface cannot be made

Дело в шрифте. А именно в поддерживаемом наборе символов. Скорее всего что шрифт не знает как показать тот или иной символ и шлет всех лесом.

Answer (score 0):

Папка assets должна быть на уровне с java и res. В ней папка fonts где уже и лежат шрифты. Иначе получаем  RuntimeException: native typeface cannot be made